# Processing large number of messages in a thread-safe manner

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgres, .net-core

I have the following use case and would like to implement it in a thread-safe manner. Think of a Stack Overflow-like web application.

1. Somebody upvotes a question.
2. A new event is sent to the message broker. Data sent are `{type: "Upvote", userId: "10"}`
3. A background service reads the event.
4. Reads the current point count for the user `10` from the database.
5. Adds 10 points.
6. Saves the value to the database.

Now imagine how many upvotes are created every second on Stack Overflow, across different users.
How can I make my code work properly and not be a bottleneck, but still support a large number of concurrent requests for point calculation?

My first thought was to just make my message broker client read one message at a time, but that will affect throughput.

My second thought was to create a thread-safe cache that holds points per user, but how can I write that to the database in a thread-safe manner? Is it even ok to do database access inside a lock?

Maybe there is a way to cache points per user for a while and then flush them periodically to the database? But what if the server goes down unexpectedly and my state is not flushed?

What other options are there?

Comment: You almost certainly don't have to implement something on Stack Overflow's scale.

Comment: This is just for a hobby project. I like to pretend I have important problems to solve. Makes my the project more fun, albeit overly complicated.

Comment: If you take the 560M from http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/7/21/stackoverflow-update-560m-pageviews-a-month-25-servers-and-i.html (so it's an old number), that meant 216 page views per second. And the number of votes is far less. If you look at your profile on SO, your posts have been seen by ~139k people, but the 1500 rep suggests that less than 200 of them voted anything (every ~700th). And if you look at a top user, https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet, he has 1.3M rep, so let's say 150k voters, out of 333M views. Every ~2200th voted only. And then I still ignored bounties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using a single SQL database to contain the data.

1. "Update users set score = score + 10 where userid = @userid"

This is reasonably fast, row level locking. But you just have a score, you lose the tie back to the vote.

2. "Insert into votes...." "select sum(votes) where userid=@userid"

Inserting is fast and doesn't lock, but the aggregate select is very slow even if you avoid locking.

I would suggest the following

When a user votes:

```
"Insert into votes..."
```

Have a backend process calculating the sum of votes and storing the users score.

```
foreach User in users
{
   //slow calc
   "select sum(votes)"
   //update row
   "update user set score = @score"
}
```

User wants to see their score

```
"select score from user where id = @id"
```

This allows you to take your time with the score calculation with the downside of the user not immediately seeing their score update.

You can optimise further, maybe remember the date if the last score calculation so you only have to look at new rows and scale out the score calculation process by splitting the users amongst multiple workers. Have a message queue notify the calculator that a users score needs updating rather than looping though the whole list etc

The point is that when your site is under load, rather than going down users will just have a delay in their score updating.

Comment: I am guessing your proposal #1 is meant as a stored procedure? So then I would not have to mess around with locking inside the app, but simply have my app call this one stored proc and let the database handle the concurrency?

Comment: @robotron In most rdbms a stored procedure is not needed for Ewan's #1. It can be dynamic sql, prepared statement, or stored procedure as you or your toolset prefer. Otherwise I think you got the point.

Comment: I would not use a sproc. the lock will be the same regardless of how you run the sql

Comment: Yeah, you are both right, no need for sproc, rdbms takes care of serializing the calls.